# Is my Internet Explorer up to date?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-update

Is my Internet Explorer up to date? I have version 11.0.9600.16428 whatever that means. The copyright date is 2013 which made me suspicious.

I don't think its automatic update works in our office. Can I update it manually somehow?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department. By the way it is **not** the latest version.

Comment: Why are you concerned?  IE11 was first released in 2013.  IE12 will likely have a 2015 copyright date which will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version of IE(on windows 8.1) as of 11th Dec 2014 is 11.0.9600.17498

You can download KB3008923 from here [KB3008923 from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=KB3008923%20Internet%20Explorer%2011) or  [Win 8.1 x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45138) or [Win 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45148)